# Want to upload a sqlite.db file to a swift container using python swiftclient and always get a utf-8 error

Tags: python, swift, python-3.x, openstack, openstack-swift

i am trying to upload a sqlite.db(binary file) to a swift container using swiftclient in my python code.

import swiftclient
swift_conn.put_object

> File "/usr/lib/python3.7/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
>       (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
>   UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xbc in position 43: invalid start byte

the code i am using is:

`import swiftclient
bmdatabase = "./logs/test.db'
    with open(bmdatabase, 'r') as bmdatabase_file:
                #remote
                correctbmdatabasename = bmdatabase.replace("./logs/", "")
                swift_conn.put_object(container_name,correctbmdatabasename,
                                      contents=bmdatabase_file.read())`

Comment: code seems incomplete, where does `swift_conn` comes from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found it by myself, if I want to read a binary file I have to read it with 'rb'

like

```
import swiftclient
bmdatabase = "./logs/test.db'
    with open(bmdatabase, 'rb') as bmdatabase_file:
                #remote
                correctbmdatabasename = bmdatabase.replace("./logs/", "")
                swift_conn.put_object(container_name,correctbmdatabasename,
                                      contents=bmdatabase_file.read())
```